# How far can Keycloak scale in terms of resources and permissions?

Tags: permissions, resources, keycloak

I'm planning on having hundred of thousands of entities in my application and I want to handle rights on each of these. I won't be the one handling those rights, my users will and they probably won't set rights on every entity.

How far can Keycloak go on this matter? I probably should be creating resources for only the elements that actually need specific permissions but I want to understand when things may become an issue and when I should be trying to find an other solution.

Thanks

Comment: Good question :). Curious to see what would be the answer.

Comment: Me as well, but I have the felling that it will closed :/