# How to implement permission-based access control to a resource owned by a group a user is part of in Keycloak?

Tags: permissions, authorization, keycloak

I'm trying to achieve group ownership on a resource inside Keycloak. As far as I know it's not directly possible. Check [KEYCLOAK-5122](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-5122). I'm really not sure how [KEYCLOAK-7353](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-7353) makes it not needed anymore.

I have the following:

- My users are inside groups that have a functional use in my application.
- Users in a group can create entities that are then owned by the group (any user from that group can access the entities underneath it)
- I want to check the following: `CAN currentUser DO entities:view ON selectedGroup ?`. This allows me to see if a user can list all entities from a specific group.

I want Keycloak to handle my permissions. I see two possibilities:

1. Solution 1: For each group I create:

   - I also create a resource
   - I create a Group policy for that group
   - I create a permission using that policy, the scope I want to allow (entities:view), and the group resource I created.
   - **So I'm creating 1 resource, 1 policy and 1 permission per group**
2. Solution 2:

   - For each group I create a resource with an attribute `group_id` that references the group's ID and a specific type for all group typed resources.
   - I create a JS Policy that checks a resource's group_id attribute against the user's groups.
   - I create a permission using that policy, the scope I want to allow (entities:view), and the resource type used for groups.
   - **Here i'm only creating a  resource per group and everything else would work in a generic way**

I don't really like any of those two solutions to be honest.

- The first one seems a no go for me because it seems like too much policies and permissions in the end. I actually asked a question about that: [How far can Keycloak scale in terms of resources and permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968089/how-far-can-keycloak-scale-in-terms-of-resources-and-permissions)
- The second one I don't like because I'm not really keeping things simple here: I need JS code that I need to provide through a JAR unless I activate the [upload_script deprecated feature](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#using-keycloak-administration-console-to-upload-scripts).

I feel like I'm missing something here. If I had to ask my question in a more generic way I would say:
**How to implement access control based on a business-related owner easily ?**

EDIT: I went with solution 1 for now but I'm facing some other kind of issues. Check out [KEYCLOAK-16515](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-16515)

Comment: Which framework you use for your application?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot. But i'm not sure this will help answer my question which is more related to how I should be configuring Keycloak (through an API probably) than how to code the interactions.